# Using blender as a video editor, what's the best way to add a box around part of the video?

Tags: edit-mode, video-sequence-editor, video, effects

What's the best way of how would I should go about adding something as simple as this?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by using it as a video editor? Are you taking videos of a 3d scene, or actually importing video files to edit?

Comment: importing video files to edit.

Comment: imo, any video editing software at all would be waaay better than blender for this, but I will try to answer your question anyways.

Comment: Just for clarification, how are you manipulating the video in blender's 3d environment? are you displaying it in an empty?

Comment: Blender actually does really well as a stable, cross platform, OSS video editor.  Haven't ran into many issues compared to other video editors out there -- especially when talking about linux support.  Adobe and others are better, but OSS!

Anyways, to answer, no I am not using the 3d environment at all.  Opening up blender, moving to the video editor, importing videos, and cutting/editing around in the timeline.

Comment: Oh alright, I guess I din't know it had that capability.

Comment: Honestly, the color effect strip is close to what I'm thinking but it creates a solid square color.  I'm looking for that to be transparent in the center, making a square box/outline like the photo.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UEIkIrYQYYY&list=PLjyuVPBuorqIhlqZtoIvnAVQ3x18sNev4 is a good playlist for specifics on some things I'm doing.

Comment: I'd go with either masks or object from 3D scene. It is also can be recreated with multiple color strips, but it is a bit tricky